# Make a non convertible pdf file

Tags: pdf

I want to make a script that locks a pdf file and make it non convertible to other types WORD or TXT.

Is there any script to make this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: For what purpose?  If the PDF contains text, that text can be copied/pasted.  If you're trying to prevent people from copying data at all, they can always take a screen shot.

Comment: Yes true, but I just want to know if that's possible with some scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Not really.  I mean, there are ways but the effort expended is rarely worth it.

One of the simplest ways is to start with creating the document with an owner password and no user password.  This lets anyone open the file, but will abide by the user access permissions in the encrypt dictionary.  Permissions you can set can include:

- Allow/Deny printing
- Allow/Deny copying text/images
- Allow/Deny modifying text annots and form fields

This will work with Acrobat, but doesn't stop any 3rd party tools from allowing this.

You could also make your own font that had an "unusual" encoding but reads correctly.  This is equivalent to encoding your document with a Caesar cipher, which is not even encryption by any modern definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question multiple times and researched different answers. I work as an engineer that writes documents sometimes for several subcontracted jobs and even sub it out to other technicians. They need my paperwork for those specific jobs but I don't want anyone copying my paperwork. I found converting a MS Word file to PDF can always be undone. I found the easiest way for me (though time consuming) was to print the document, then scan after printing as a pdf. That would make the text non-editable. Hope this helps.